# Connecting SFTP server using the certificate

Tags: adapter, sftp, biztalk, biztalk-2013

One of our vendor is updating their Server certificate and provided us with the certificate file which when I open gets installed. Not sure where it gets installed. Earlier we were just using the username/password credentials for connecting to the server. But I am trying to check if we can the connect to the SFTP server using the certificates through the SFTP adapter. If so how do I link the SFTP adapter settings with the installed certificates.

Comment: Certificates are not used with SFTP. Maybe you mean FTPS? And server certificates are not used for authentication. So your question actually hardly makes any sense.

Answer (score 1):

For clarity, SFTP does not use Certificates.  The options are U/P with server provider key or **Private Key**.

So, seems they will be sending you a Private Key File they generate which you can import using the Private Key Property on SFTP Transport Properties.

Comment: You do not use host private key for authentication. You mean user/account private key. And that you should generate on your own, no one should be sending you a private key.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Same difference as host provided Private Keys are not at all uncommon in this scenario, which is what the vendor must be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Installed certificates will be in your certificate store, run certmgr to see what certificates are installed.  However the BizTalk adapter seems to want the location of the .ppk file.

To use the certificate you will have to configure the Client Authentication Mode to PublicKeyAuthentication and you must enter the private key of the user in the PrivateKey property.

See the Microsoft documentation [SFTP Adapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/sftp-adapter) and this blog [BizTalk Server 2013 R2: SFTP Adapter Tricks and Pitfalls](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33638.biztalk-server-2013-r2-sftp-adapter-tricks-and-pitfalls.aspx)